# How to make a plot of a negative binomial regression (fitted values and 95% confidence bands) when using offset variables?

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to make a plot of a negative binomial model in R but I cannot even extract the confidence limits for the fitted values when using offset variables. Is there any way to make a plot without trying to get the 95% CIs manually?

```
y <- c(602,38,616,256,21,723,245,176,89,1614,31,27,313,251,345)
x <- c(31,35,21,30,37,26,45,21,74,27,37,37,31,37,25)
offset_1 <-c(72,50,31,30,16,25,75,16,78,40,68,25,71,52,17) 
newdata <- data.frame(y,x,offset_1)
nb.model <- MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x + offset(log(offset_1)), data=newdata)
summary(nb.model)
predict(nb.model, type="response")/newdata$offset_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `emmeans` + `ggplot` (`ggeffects`/`sjPlot` might automate the process a bit further, but I like the control of doing it myself). Handling offsets in `emmeans` is discussed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html#offsets).

```r
library(emmeans)
## generated predicted values / CIs
ee <- emmeans(nb.model, ~x,
       at = list(x = seq(20,75, length.out = 51)), 
       type = "response", offset = log(1))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(ee), aes(x, response)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), 
                colour = NA, alpha = 0.2) +
    ## add observed data
    geom_point(data = newdata, aes(y=y/offset_1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any direct method (apart from maybe the ggeffects package) of plotting the confidence intervals from a negative binomial model with an offset though we can use broom to return the standard error of the fit and calculate the confidence intervals using a normal approximation (Wald confidence interval).

```r
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
conf_level <- 0.95
cval <- qnorm(1 - ( (1 - conf_level) / 2))
augment(nb.model, se_fit = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(lcl = .fitted - cval * .se.fit,
         ucl = .fitted + cval * .se.fit) %>%
  mutate(across(c(.fitted, lcl, ucl), exp)) %>%
  mutate(across(c(y, .fitted, lcl, ucl), ~ .x / exp(offset(log(offset_1))))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = lcl), lty = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = ucl), lty = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Ben suggested, here is also the "automated process" using the *ggeffects* package. The package warns the user about probably inaccurate predictions due to the involvement of transformed offsets.

```r
library(ggeffects)
newdata <- data.frame(
  y = c(602, 38, 616, 256, 21, 723, 245, 176, 89, 1614, 31, 27, 313, 251, 345),
  x = c(31, 35, 21, 30, 37, 26, 45, 21, 74, 27, 37, 37, 31, 37, 25),
  offset_1 = c(72, 50, 31, 30, 16, 25, 75, 16, 78, 40, 68, 25, 71, 52, 17)
)

m <- MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x + offset(log(offset_1)), data = newdata)
pr <- ggemmeans(m, "x") # use "x [20:75]" for smoother plots
#> Model uses a transformed offset term. Predictions may not be correct.
#>   Please apply transformation of offset term to the data before fitting
#>   the model and use `offset(offset_1)` in the model formula.
#>   You could also fix the offset term using the `condition` argument, e.g.
#>   `condition = c(offset_1 = 1)`.
plot(pr, add.data = TRUE)
#> Data points may overlap. Use the `jitter` argument to add some amount of
#>   random variation to the location of data points and avoid overplotting.
```

[image]

You can fix the offset term at a specific value, using the `condition` argument. However, for plots, the original data was not adjusted, so predictions and original data do not properly match when using the current CRAN version of the *ggeffects* package. But this is fixed in the lasted version of *ggeffects* and you can now reproduce the same results shown in Ben's posting:

```r
pr <- ggemmeans(m, "x [20:75]", condition = c(offset_1 = 1))
plot(pr, add.data = TRUE)
#> Data points may overlap. Use the `jitter` argument to add some amount of
#>   random variation to the location of data points and avoid overplotting.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To install the latest package version, use `ggeffects::install_latest()`, which installs the latest GitHub version (from a CRAN-like server, so you don't need any tools that would be required when installing packages from source).